# How many years of his life sentence will Nicolas Godejohn actually have to serve?

Tags: united-states, parole

He was sentenced to life in prison for the first degree murder of Deedee Blanchard, but I note that it wasn’t life without parole. So what does this mean in practice? How much do such sentenceees commonly serve of their sentences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

N.G. was [sentenced to life *without* the possibility of parole](https://www.news-leader.com/story/news/crime/2018/11/16/nicholas-godejohn-found-guilty-blanchard-murder/2027186002/).

Comment: Is it a standard/ common practice to refer to criminal defendants by their initials?

Comment: I thought we wernt allowed linkonly answers ?

Comment: @Heddy I think this answer is fine both by the [letter of the rules](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and by its spirit. Link-only answers are disallowed because if the link rots the answer becomes useless, but here, Jen gave the important part and the link is just proof of it. It’s a short answer, sure, but if it is complete...